# How to get rid of string concatenation for SQL query

Tags: c++, mysql, database, qt, qt5

I just wrote the following code:

```
QSqlQuery query(_db);
QString sql =
    "SELECT company_name, server_name, product_name, product_version, license_end, last_update, comment"
    " FROM foo WHERE";
if (!include_unlimited)
{
    sql += " license_end > NOW() AND license_end != '9999-01-01'";
}
else if (!include_trial)
{
    sql += " license_end = '9999-01-01'";
}
else
{
    sql += " license_end > NOW()";
}
if (product_name != "*")
{
    sql += " AND product_name = :product_name";
}
sql += " ORDER BY license_end";
query.prepare(
    sql
);
if (sql.contains(":product_name"))
{
    query.bindValue(":product_name", product_name);
}
query.exec();
while (query.next())
{
    LicenseInfo license;
    license.company_name = query.value(0).toString();
    license.server_name = query.value(1).toString();
    license.product_name = query.value(2).toString();
    license.product_version = query.value(3).toInt();
    license.license_end = query.value(4).toString();
    license.last_update = query.value(5).toString();
    license.comment = query.value(6).toString();
    licenses.append(license);
}
```

How to get rid of this string concatenation for the SQL query?

Comment: What exactly is the question

Comment: @sagi I think that the manual string concatenation looks ugly and I wonder what is the best way to re-write this code

Comment: The only way I can think of(since the query depends on conditions) is instead of concate them, just use sql = WHOLE QUERY . maybe it will be more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to concatenate, you just write the whole query, involving all the preconditions and use bind variables to enable, disable where clauses. Something like this:

```
SELECT company_name, server_name, product_name
     , product_version, license_end, last_update, comment
  FROM foo
 WHERE (   (:include_unlimited IS NOT NULL AND license_end > NOW() AND license_end != '9999-01-01') 
        OR (:include_trial IS NOT NULL AND license_end = '9999-01-01')
        OR (:include_trial IS NULL AND :include_unlimited IS NULL AND license_end > NOW())
       )
   AND (product_name = :product_name OR :product_name = '*')
 ORDER BY product_name
```

I haven't tested it on MySQL, but have used this approach in some cases where one has to implement a lot of logic in single select statement.

The binding part would then probably then look like:

```
query.bindValue(":include_trial", include_trial ? QVariant(include_trial) : QVariant());
```